# Java Swing display problem

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a gui program in SWING but i have a strange problem.
I have a frame, a panel, a menu and the components. I put all the components in the panel and then i add this and the menu to the frame.

When I run the program it shows up only a window with the menu but if i maximaze the window or just change a little the dimesions of the window while it's running all the components shows up!

Is this a bug or something?

Comment: Yes, check layouts that you use!

Comment: do you add the panel with the components _after_ you draw the frame (resp. set the visibilty of the frame `true`)?

Comment: I didn't use a layout, i used the visual editor with layout set to null. If i try to pack i take as result a window in the size of the menu although i had add the panel to the frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're probably seeing is that components have not been laid out by your layout manager at first, which only happens when the frame is resized.

I suspect you will want to call frame.pack() after adding your components.....

Comment: Yes this would solve my problem if i used a layout manager...i used the visual editor of eclipse and i had set the layout manager to null so if i try to use pack i get an exception...Edit: not an exception, i take a very small window with only the close button and the menu..

Comment: You were right about the frame.pack(). But right after this method i call the frame.setSize() so i can have the dimesions i want with my components!

Answer (score 6):

Can't repeat it often enough: Do use a LayoutManager!